# Partitioning a List into more than two partitions

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a list:

```
val list1 = List("male:Adam", "male:Peter", "female:Jane", "female:Sue", "female:Jo", "other:John")
```

I want to create two lists, one of female names and one of male names.
i.e.:

```
List("Adam", "Peter")
List("Jane", "Sue", "Jo")
```

I've done this with

```
val result = list1.groupBy(_.startsWith("male"))
```

So that `result` has the two lists mapped against `true` and `false` but with each element being `"male:Adam"` etc. But then I'd have to cycle through each list removing the `male:` and `female:` strings. This smells of non-functional.

Can anyone show how the above problem would be solved in a functional way?

Comment: Do you care about "other:John"? Should it go any any of those two lists, or on a third list, or be discarded?

Comment: No. either on a 3rd list or discarded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val map = list1.map(s => s.split(":") match { 
  case Array(sex, name) => (sex, name) 
})
.groupBy { case (sex, name) => sex }
.mapValues(_.map{ case (sex, name) => name })

val male = map("male")
// List(Adam, Peter)
val female = map("female")
// List(Jane, Sue, Jo)
```

Comment: Nice use of pattern matching for safer array access, +1

Comment: Loving this one!! Can you recommend any books where such style can be learned?

Comment: @AdamDavies Any book on Scala should be OK. You could also take a good look to all the functions the Scala Collections API provides ([`List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List), [`Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map), ...)

Comment: I like this answer and the use of pattern matching. Not sure I understand it but that's the fun part....Well done! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
val groups = list.map(_.split(":")).groupBy(_(0)).mapValues(_.map(_(1)))

val males = groups("male")
val females = groups("female")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map function like

```
result(true).map(_.split(":")(1))
```

Comment: `result(false).map(_.split(":")(1))` returns `List(Jane, Sue, Jo, John)` John should not be in the list. It is because of these little quirks why I'm  having the problem.

I tried `list1.groupBy(_.startsWith("male") || _.startsWith("female"))` but the second use of `_` throws a missing parameter error, which is what mystified my in the first place (hence the title of this post) :)

Comment: @AdamDavies: `_.foo` is just a shorthand for `s => s.foo`, but when you want to use the parameter multiple times, you can't use the shorthand notation. It needs to be `s => s.startsWith("male") || s.startsWith("female")` in your example.

Comment: There's no "second use of the _" in your question, so I changed the title. It seems your question isn't really about that, anyway